# How to get this image in the correct position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im creating a browser game and have a problem with my code.
Take a look at this screenshot: 
[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/m68jpq)

When the ships faces East, South or West. It is positioned in the correct grid: C4. When you switch the heading to north, you should still be in c4 but it puts you into grid b4. Another screenshot: [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/m68k7g)

I really don't understand why it does this. I can pull it down with css but that stops the animation from being called.

This is the code i have:

```
//css
<style>
#myAnimationRight {
  background-image: url("images/ships/ship<?php echo $_SESSION['getshiptype']; ?>right.png");
  background-size:     cover;                      
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  width:55px;
  top:30px;
  left: 1px;
}
#myAnimationLeft {
  background-image: url("images/ships/ship<?php echo $_SESSION['getshiptype']; ?>left.png");
  background-size:     cover;                      
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  width:55px;
  top:30px;
  right: 1px;
}
#myAnimationUp {
  background-image: url("images/ships/ship<?php echo $_SESSION['getshiptype']; ?>up.png");
  background-size:     cover;                      
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  height:55px;
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  bottom:1px;
  right: 30px;
}
#myAnimationDown {
  background-image: url("images/ships/ship<?php echo $_SESSION['getshiptype']; ?>down.png");
  background-size:     cover;                      
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  height:55px;
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  top:1px;
  right: 30px;
}
</style>
// javascripts
<script>
  function myMoveRight() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimationRight");  
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
    Clock.pause();
    function frame() {
      if (pos == 105) {
        clearInterval(id);
        Clock.resume();
        keymanager.resume();
      } else {
        pos++;
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        keymanager.suspend();
      }
    }
    MoveShip();
  }
</script>
<script>
  function myMoveLeft() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimationLeft");  
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
    Clock.pause();
    function frame() {
      if (pos == 105) {
        clearInterval(id);
        Clock.resume();
        keymanager.resume();
      } else {
        pos++;
        elem.style.right = pos + 'px';
        keymanager.suspend();
      }
    }
    MoveShip();
  }
</script>
<script>
  function myMoveDown() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimationDown");  
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
    Clock.pause();
    function frame() {
      if (pos == 105) {
        clearInterval(id);
        Clock.resume();
        keymanager.resume();
      } else {
        pos++;
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        keymanager.suspend();
      }
    }
    MoveShip();
  }
</script>
<script>
  function myMoveUp() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimationUp");  
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
    Clock.pause();
    function frame() {
      if (pos == 105) {
        clearInterval(id);
        Clock.resume();
        keymanager.resume();
      } else {
        pos++;
        elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px';
        keymanager.suspend();
      }
    }
    MoveShip();
  }
</script>
//html / php
<?php
        if($shipheading == "E")
        {
          echo '<div id ="myAnimationRight"></div>';
        }
        elseif($shipheading == "W")
        {
          echo '<div id ="myAnimationLeft"></div>';
        }
        elseif($shipheading == "S")
        {
          echo '<div id ="myAnimationDown"></div>';
        }
        elseif($shipheading == "N")
        {
          echo '<div id ="myAnimationUp"></div>';
        }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick CSS tip, it appears in your 4 animation ID's that you are only changing one thing, the background-image.  You can combine all the common properties like so: `#myAnimationRight, #myAnimationLeft, #myAnimationUp, #myAnimationDown { background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; etc etc }`

Comment: Also, you only need one set of `<script>` tags.  Put all your JS functions into one set of `<script>` tags.

Comment: Where and how are the myMovexx functions being called?  I'm guessing on specific keystrokes like arrow keys?

Comment: Its not only the image. Its also the width, height, position etc.. About the mymove functions, yes. They are called with arrow keys. I can pull the position down with css to get it in the right position but that disables the animation.